# Socket.io is defined, but socket.io.sockets aren't

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm experiencing a strange issue.
In my very basic server I have:

```
server.listen(8001);
io.listen(server);
var sockets = io.sockets;
```

Unfortunately sockets is undefined.

Do you have any explanation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`io.listen()` returns an instance of the Socket.io class. It's the instance that has a `sockets` property, not the class itself:

```
server.listen(8001);
var mySocketIoInstance = io.listen(server);
var sockets = mySocketIoInstance.sockets;
```

(This is assuming that the variable `io` is the Socket.io class, not an instance of Socket.io which *also* has a `.listen` method)